# Update Order column with number increasing (depend on ID column)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using the SQL Server 2008.

Now I have the scenario as description below:

- 1 table with 3 columns: ID, Name, Order.
- They has 8 records.
- 5 records have the same data: ID='1', Name='AAA'
- 3 records have the same data: ID='2', Name='BBB'

Now I want to update Order column with number increasing (start from 1) for each ID,Name:

```
    No  Name    Order
1   AAA 1
1   AAA 2
1   AAA 3
1   AAA 4
1   AAA 5
2   BBB 1
2   BBB 2
2   BBB 3
```

How can I get this result without using Cursors?

I'm very appriciated for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following.  I use CTE to drive the update statement

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT Order
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME 
                                ORDER BY ID, NAME) AS Seq
      FROM TableA
)
UPDATE data
   SET Order = Seq
```

Substitute TableA with your table name

Comment: Yeah, your sample definately solved my problem. Thank you very much.